# How to correctly use BackgroundWorker to call static method with arguments

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, background-process

I see that BackgroundWorker class able to pass to upper process some progress information. I have static method:

```
MyClass.MyMethod(string, string)    // Does some work which progress I need to report
```

how can I use such method from any calling function or process to return BackgroundWorker progress info like this for example:

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percent, "Stage N 1...");
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to True.

Than add an event handler to the [Progress changed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx)
and at least add your code into the new handler.

for example:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var percent = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

But at least: The Background worker class is more or less Obsolete ( [Windows statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) ) i would like to use the new [Task class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

Comment: I mean that MyClass.MyMethod(string, string) takes some necessary arguments not connected with progress info - percent (int), message (string). MyMethod should call ReportProgress in necessary places.

Comment: Code part is removed from example, but i still recommend the use of Task or Asnyc not BackgroundWorker